# Display XML with XSLT transform in WebBrowser in Windows Phone 8/8.1

Tags: c#, xml, windows, xslt, windows-phone-8

I have an XML document with the XSLT transform document (included in the XML, but I may pull it out if needed).
I need to display it in the WebBrowser component, but if I submit the document by calling

```
WebBrowser.NavigateToString(myXmlDocument)
```

it displays an incorrect content.
I tried to convert the document using **XDocument** and **XslCompiledTransform**, but the latter is unavailable in Windows Phone 8 SDK. Is there some way to work around this and to make the transform, or to display the content correctly in the WebBrowser control?

**UPDATE**:

We found that the Windows Phone WebBrowser is bugged in xslt processing, so we tried:

- To use an alternative browser, but none of these seem to work
- To use an external XML library to process the XSLT transform, but found none.

Comment: Does the Windows Phone web browser support XSLT? In that case I would assume that MSXML 3 and/or MSXML 6 is available via COM interop and you could try the approach suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/a/10127689/252228.

Comment: Did not find MSXML on Windows Phone. How do you connect the component?